# Is it possible to do Mutual SSL Authentication on Google App Engine Environment?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

actually we want to authenticate user depends on client certificate.

here is the process,

1. We will issue a client certificate for each device.(it will be a selfSign certificate)
2. We would like to enable Server with client certificate authentication.

only users who attempt to connect from clients loaded with the right client certificates will succeed. 
Even if a legitimate user attempts to connect with the right username and password, 
if that user isn't on a client application loaded with the right client certificate,
that user will not be granted access.

We would like to identify\authenticate each device\user with a unqiue certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn’t appear to be supported by App Engine. There is currently a request filed for this feature to allow authentication with App Engine using SSL certificates based on user device and you can view updates [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/111860015).